# How to programatically route in React within a state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, state

I'm new to React and using Zustand to handle global stores. **My goal in this particular instance is to route to an "RSVP" page if the correct user is found.**

> Scenario A: User is found in the database. Route to new page
>
> Scenario B: User is not found in the database. Stay on current page and display error message

It seems straightforward if you want to achieve this on click, however I can't find any information on how to trigger it within a state.

My understanding is that useHistory can be used, but only within a function, so it doesn't work when I try to use it in a state. eg.

```
import create from 'zustand';
import { mountStoreDevtool } from 'simple-zustand-devtools';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";


const useStore = create((set, get) => ({
  guests: [],
  currentGuests: [],
  message: "Please enter your unique password found in your email.",
  returnDatabase: (input) => {
    const guests = get().guests;

    const targetParty = guests.filter((guest) => guest.party === input);
    
    if (targetParty.length !== 0) {
      set({ currentGuests: targetParty });
      const setMessage = "Please enter your unique password found in your email.";
      set({ message: setMessage });

      //I want to programatically redirect here
      let history = useHistory();
      history.push("/rsvp");

    } else {
      const setMessage = "Your password has not been found. Please check your email and try again.";
      set({ message: setMessage });
    }
  
  },
  setStore: (data) => {
    const guestsData = data.guests;
    set({ guests: guestsData });
  },
}));
```

However, I'm receiving this error:

```
Failed to compile
src/store/storeUtil.js
  Line 19:21:  React Hook "useHistory" is called in function "returnDatabase" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

I figure this is because it's not in a function, so I tried to put it in a separate component:

```
import create from 'zustand';
import { mountStoreDevtool } from 'simple-zustand-devtools';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

  export function RsvpButton(){
    let history = useHistory();
  
    function handleClick() {
      history.push("/rsvp");
    }
  
    return (
      {handleClick}
    );
  }


const useStore = create((set, get) => ({
  guests: [],
  currentGuests: [],
  message: "Please enter your unique password found in your email.",
  returnDatabase: (input) => {
    const guests = get().guests;

    const targetParty = guests.filter((guest) => guest.party === input);
    
    if (targetParty.length !== 0) {
      set({ currentGuests: targetParty });
      const setMessage = "Please enter your unique password found in your email.";
      set({ message: setMessage });

      //try to use component here 
      <RsvpButton />

...etc
```

And this just doesn't do anything/have any errors. Should I be using a different method to route to the RSVP page other than useHistory? Or am I doing something wrong in my implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Your button component **RsvpButton** is not creating a button.

The code for function RsvpButton should be something like

```
export function RsvpButton () {
    ... 
    return (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Rsvp</button>
    ) 
}
```

That way, the `handleClick` function will be linked to the `onClick` property of the button, which will make it run upon clicking the button.

Comment: Hi Rituraj, thanks for the answer. My problem is, I want it to trigger manually (i.e. not on click) depending on the logic. 

If user is on the list: Trigger route
If user is not on the list: Stay on same page and display error message 

I'll edit the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for anyone having a similar issue:

To solve this, I put the useHistory handler in the parent component
RsvpContainer.js

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
    useEffect(() => {
      loadData();
    });
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="header">
                <div className="Bg section-2"></div>
                <div className="divider"></div>
                <div className="App section-2">
                    <h3>RSVP.</h3>
                    <h2>Saturday 30 October, 2021</h2>
                    <Input 
                        filter={filter} 
                        setFilter={setFilter}
                        returnDatabaseHandler={returnDatabaseHandler}
                        onUserFound={onUserFoundHandler}
                    />
                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
```

Input.js

```
export function Input({ setFilter, filter, onUserFound }) {
  const isUserFound = useStore((state) => state.isUserFound);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isUserFound) {
      onUserFound();
    }
  }, [isUserFound]);

}
```

storeUtil.js (zustand global store) - I added this in 'returnDatabase'

```
  set({
    message: setMessage,
    isUserFound: true
  });
```